# Python3: how to use module 'Import click' & Parsing command line

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, command-line, command

I am a hobby radio amateur [G6SGA] not a programmer but I do try. :)
using python3. I am trying to do the following and really can't get my head around - argparse and ended up trying to use 'Import click'. Still can't get my head around so here I am.  Any all (polite) :) suggestions welcome.
I wish to ---

**cmd line**> python3 scratch.py  **[no options supplied]**

output> "Your defaults were used and are:9600 and '/dev/ttyAMA0' "

or

**cmd line**> python3 scratch.py 115200 '/dev/ttyABC123'

output> "Your input values were used and are: 115200 and '/dev/ttyAMA0'"

so a command line that will take [or NOT] argument/s. store the argument to a variable in the code for future use.
This some of what I have tried:  Yes I accept it's a mess

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf_8 -*-
#   ========================
#   Include standard modules
#   import click
#   baud default = 9600
#   port default = "/dev/ttyAMA0"
import click

@click.command()
#   @click.option('--baud', required = False, default = 9600, help = 'baud rate defaults to: 9600')
#   @click.option('--port', required = False, default = '/dev/ttyAMA0', help = 'the port to use defaults to: /dev/ttyAMA0')
@click.option('--item', type=(str, int))


def putitem(item):
    click.echo('name=%s id=%d' % item)


def communications():
    """ This checks the baud rate and port to use
    either the command line supplied item or items.
    Or uses the default values
    abaud = 9600 #   default baud rate
    b=abaud
    aport = "/dev/ttyAMA0"
    p=aport
    print(f"abaud = {b} and aport = {p}")
    """

    #   now I wish to check if there were supplied values
    #   on the command line
    #   print(f"Baud supplied {click.option.} port supplied {port}" )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    putitem()       #    communications()
```

Comment: I have the answer I need: chuffed.

Answer (score 0):

The code I have used to work this all out is below, I hope it helps somebody. Any better ways or mistakes please advise.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf_8 -*-
import click
from typing import Tuple
#   Command Line test string:  python scratch_2.py -u bbc.co.uk aaa 9600 bbb ccc
myuri = ""      # This is a placeholder for a GLOBAL variable  -- take care!
list1 = []      # This is a placeholder for a GLOBAL variable  -- take care!
@click.command(name="myLauncher", context_settings={"ignore_unknown_options": True})
@click.option('--uri', '-u', type=click.STRING, default=False, help ="URI for the server")
@click.argument('unprocessed_args', nargs = -1, type = click.UNPROCESSED)


def main(uri: str, unprocessed_args: Tuple[str, ...]) -> None:
    #   ====================  Checking the command line structure and obtaining variables
    global myuri                    #   define the use of a GLOBAL variable in this function
    temp = list((str(j) for i in {unprocessed_args: Tuple} for j in i)) # sort out the command line arguments
    res = len(temp)
    # printing result
    print("")
    for e in range(0 ,res):         # list each of the command line elements not including any uri
        print("First check: An input line Tuple element number: " + str(e) +":   " + str(temp[e]))   #    elements base 0
                                    #   ====================  deal with any URI supplied -- or NOT
    if uri is False:                #if  --uri or -u is not supplied
        print("No uri supplied\n")
        print("The input line tuple list elements count: " + str(res))
                                    #   set a defaul GLOBAL value of myuri if it is not supplied
        myuri = "https://192.168.0.90:6691/"        #
    else:
        print("\nThe input line tuple list elements count : " + str(res) + " and we got a uri")
        myuri = uri                 #   set the GLOBAL value of myuri if the uri is
        print(f"which is: {uri}, and therefore myuri also is: {myuri}")     #    a temp print to prove the values of the GLOBAL variable 'myuri'
    #   ==============================================================================================
    #   Testing choice of baud rate on command line
    db_list = {
        '4800': 'TEST48',
        '9600': 'TEST96',
        '19200': 'TEST19',
        '38400': 'TEST38',
        '57600': 'TEST57',
        '115200': 'TEST11',
   }
    # Print databases  ----- db_list ----- listed in dictionary
    print("\nDatabases:")

    for e in range(0 ,res) :
        """ list each of the command line elements not including any uri
        print("Second Check: An input line Tuple element number: " + str(e) +":   " + str(temp[e]))
        elements base 0 """
        if str(temp[e]) in db_list.keys() :
            print(f"The index of db contains {str(temp[e])}, The index refers to: {db_list[str(temp[e])]}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter, unexpected-keyword-arg
    main()
```